# Remove style from some controls when Print

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

i hav a form which contains some textboxs , i looking for a way to remove its style when i click on buton Print  . i have an idea how to hide for exemple any control when i click Print button with this way :

```
 @media print  { 
            .screenOnly { display: none; }
          }

<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript : window.print();"
                    OnClick="Button4_Click1" OnPreRender="Button4_PreRender1" CssClass="btn screenOnly" />
```

but to remove controls style i have no idea !!!!!!!
Thank you

Comment: You should be able to use a "print" css. You should be able to find example print css with a google search.

Comment: Or go the other way: make a `only screen` media query for the styles that you do want only on the screen.

Comment: sorry but what only screen media query ?

Answer (score 0):

To have styles in your page for use on the screen but not on the printed page, put them in a media query of their own. Example:

```css
div {color: green}                /* always */

@media screen {
   div {font-weight:bold}         /* only on the screen */
}

@media print {
   div {font-variant: small-caps} /* only in print */
}
```

See [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#background) for much more info.